# How to populate tinymce with some content on trigger of javascript event?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

i want to populate the tinymce body with some content on trigger of onchange event of selectbox in javascript. I tried some stuff but it did
not work for me.Please guide me in right direction.
Here is the my code that appends the tinymce on textarea

```
$(function() {
appendTinyMCE();
function appendTinyMCE(){
    tinyMCE.init({

        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "preview",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,|,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,sub,sup,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true

});}
```

});

here is the html code

```
<td>
        <textarea rows="15" name="MyTinymceContent" cols="90" >MyTestContent</textarea>
```

Now i want to populate the tinymce with new content , on change of select box in javascript. So i write the below code snippet on change
 of select box

```
 function populateMyTinyMCE() {
  document.form.MyTinymceContent.value ="MyNewContent";
 }
```

**But it does not put the new content in tinymce body. I am not sure what i am missing here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call any of following on some event trigger:

```
tinyMCE.get('your_editor').setContent("MyNewContent");
//OR
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('MyNewContent');
```

See: [Here for More](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.setContent)

Comment: Hey Sudhir , tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('MyNewContent') worked for me. Out of curiosity, if i want to use tinyMCE.get('your_editor').setContent("MyNewContent"), what  should i place instead of 'your_editor' as i do not see any id attribute inside tinymce.

Comment: if your textarea does not have an id "content" will be used as default

Answer (score 3):

Tinymce is not equal the textarea. On initialization of the editor a contenteditable iframe get created. This iframe holds the editor content and gets written back into the editor source html element (in your case a textarea) from time to time. To set the editor content you need to use the tinymce `setContent` function. I will show the alternatives too:

```
 function populateMyTinyMCE() {

    var editor = tinymce.editors[0];

    // other ways to get the editor instance
    // editor = tinymce.get('my editor id');
    // editor = tinymce.activeEditor;

    editor.setContent('my new content');

    // alternate way of setting the content
    // editor.getBody().innerHTML = 'my new content';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("MyNewContent");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I missed in the above (and other online) examples.

This is the correct format:

```
tinymce.get('your_textarea_id').setContent(var_with_html);
```

HOWEVER (!)

1. The ID string cannot have the # prefix. If the element has id="bob" then the command is `.get('bob')` NOT `.get('#bob')`
2. Only IDs can be used, not class names

This is the 2nd time I've had to solve this, so answering this question for my future self as much as for other devs.